# How to make oshi.hardware.Sensors information available to get. Can it be done?

Tags: java, availability, sensors, oshi

I'm trying to get the cpu temp, voltage and fan speeds using OSHI, but the results show me this info is not available. Here's my code:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
    SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
    HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
    Sensors sensors = hal.getSensors();
    System.out.println(sensors.toString());
    }
```

This is the output on Windows 10:

```
    CPU Temperature=0.0°C, Fan Speeds=[0, 0, 0], CPU Voltage=0.0
```

Here's the Sensors interface:

```
public interface Sensors {
/**
 * CPU Temperature
 *
 * @return CPU Temperature in degrees Celsius if available, 0 otherwise.
 */
double getCpuTemperature();

/**
 * Fan speeds
 *
 * @return Speed in rpm for all fans. May return empty array if no fans detected
 *         or 0 fan speed if unable to measure fan speed.
 */
int[] getFanSpeeds();

/**
 * CPU Voltage
 *
 * @return CPU Voltage in Volts if available, 0 otherwise.
 */
double getCpuVoltage();
}
```

The three functions in the interface return 0 if info's not available.

My question is can you make this info available, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I found an explanation:

Windows sensor (temperature, fans, voltage) readings are drawn from Microsoft's Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) API; however, most hardware manufacturers do not publish these readings to WMI. If a value is not available through the Microsoft API, Oshi will attempt to retrieve values as published by the Open Hardware Monitor if it is running. Only temperature sensors are detected on FreeBSD using coretemp.

I tried running it with OHM and it worked for the temperature, which is enough for me. Please, let me know if you find a way to do it for the other two variables.

Comment: As the author of that code, I'd like to know if it's available anywhere in Windows!  It's interesting that it knows you have 3 fans, but not their speeds...  Did OHM have the other values you needed (fan speed or voltage) but OSHI didn't detect them?

Comment: Here's what OHM has and what OSHI gives me after running the code: https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-core/src/test/java/oshi/SystemInfoTest.java#L1

https://file.io/4YUh9Z
https://file.io/xn3CJX

Comment: I'm sorry. Here's some links to my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ABJrv2Mx8f5drowX-Gpqgo6VS2wFtaYg/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B0iO5-J8Aj_G7iJSFSLmepaEe5Bn4yU7

Comment: Thanks for the output. Looks like OHM can't find the fan speeds or voltage, either.  Unfortunately it's really hard to get that information on Windows without specialized software.